# Синоним слова «прозрачный» в значении «понятный и честный»

Tags: синонимы

Какой самый удачный синоним у слова «прозрачный» в таком контексте?

> Это повышает уровень прозрачности процессов и экономит время на
>   взаимодействие между участниками.

Comment: "открытый"? подойдет?

Comment: Каковы ваши варианты? Что вы имеете ввиду под удачным синонимом - что есть мера удачности? Почему вам в принципе нужен синоним? Вся штука в том, что чем точнее вы зададите вопрос, тем выше вероятность, что вы получите полезный для вас ответ.

Answer (score 4):

Дело в том, что стопроцентные синонимы хоть редко, но существуют, но тогда ваш вопрос лишён смысла - зачем менять одно слово на другое, условно говоря, неотличимое от него?

Слова же, частично пересекающиеся по значению, которые, к тому же могут зависеть от контекста - для слова прозрачный это может быть и `открытый` и `простой`, и `наглядный` и (для любителей умных слов) `транспарентный` - но ни одно из них не лучше в этом конкретном предложении.

Слово "прозрачный" тут очень к месту употреблено и моим ответом будет - **никакой синоним не самый удачный**, чтобы вы под "удачным" не подразумевали.

Если же перед вами стоит задача избавиться по каким-то причинам от какого-то слова в принципе (ну, например, в тексте оно уже несколько раз употреблялось, мало ли), то иногда решение этой проблемы кроется в применении чуть более радикальных средств, чем замена синонимом - можно перекроить предложение целиком, но оставить тот же смысл.

Например, вместо "повышает уровень прозрачности процессов" можно сказать что-нибудь (опять-таки, в зависимости от контекста): "улучшает контролируемость процессов" или "помогает упросить механизмы контроля процессов" и так далее.

Answer (score 2):

Согласно [Linguee](http://www.linguee.com/english-russian/search?source=auto&query=transparency+level) английское **transparency level** переводится несколькими способами:

> - **уровень прозрачности** - очень распространено.
> - **открытость** - распространено гораздо реже
> - **транспарентность** - распространённый перевод, но лично мне не нравится

Comment: Depends on audience. "транспарентность" is a professional jargon, and was transliterated exactly to stand apart from the general language vocabulary.